# Efficient way to pipe file contents to program

Tags: bash, piping

Assume that we have command `cmd` that only takes input through a pipe. Given a filename `file.txt`, what is the most efficient way to pipe this into the command? (I assume `cat file.txt | cmd` is not very efficient ..)

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks.. Is redirection of input `<`  after the command always synonymous with a pipe `|` in front of the command? The bash manual does not mention `<` in the section of pipelines https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines

Comment: It's documented in the [redirections section of the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirecting-Input)

Comment: It can be found in the Redirection section: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections I am not entirely sure if it is always the same. For commands expecting some user input it may not work. Regarding the speed, in [Command-Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) we have _The command substitution $(cat file) can be replaced by the equivalent but faster $(< file)._

Comment: @fedorqui Ok, but can command substitution be used on the left hand side of a pipeline?

Comment: @HåkonHægland I don't know if I understand your question properly, but for example `tr -d '-' < myfile | awk '{print $1}'` is a perfect valid command that will delete dashes from `myfile` and then print the first column.

Comment: @fedorqui Ok.. I am only considering a file `file.txt` not a command on the left-hand side of the pipe...

Comment: @HåkonHægland OK. In such case, for example `awk '/1/' <file` is fine, or `wc -l < file`, etc. Note that many UNIX commands allow you to say `command file` instead of `cat file | command` or `command < file`. (I don't know if it is a POSIX especification)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's do a little test with a 1 GB blob (`dump.data`):

Using the `>` operator is much faster than piping from `cat`:

```
$ time cat dump.data | cat >/dev/null

real    0m0.360s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.608s

$ time cat <dump.data >/dev/null

real    0m0.158s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.156s
```

The only way that should theoretically be a little faster than `<` is if `cmd` accepted a filename as its argument and read the file itself (because there is no IPC involved - only one process works with the data). It does however not make any difference in this test:

```
$ time cat dump.data >/dev/null

real    0m0.158s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.156s
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other timing results

```
fn="file.txt"
[[ -e $fn ]] && rm "$fn"

for i in {1..100} ; do
    echo "Line $i" >> "$fn"
done
arg='{print FNR, $0}'
N=1000
func1() {
    for i in $(seq 1 $N) ; do
        awk "$arg" "$fn" > "$temp_file"
    done
}
func2() {
    for i in $(seq 1 $N) ; do
        cat "$fn" | awk "$arg" > "$temp_file" 
    done
}
func3() {
    for i in $(seq 1 $N) ; do
        while read line ; do
            printf "%s\n" "$line"
        done <"$fn" | awk "$arg" > "$temp_file"
    done
}
func4() {
    for i in $(seq 1 $N) ; do
        while read line ; do
            echo "$line"
        done <"$fn" | awk "$arg" > "$temp_file"
    done
}

func5() {
    for i in $(seq 1 $N) ; do
        readarray -t a <"$fn"
        printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}" | awk "$arg" > "$temp_file"
    done
}

func6() {
    for i in $(seq 1 $N) ; do
        awk "$arg" > "$temp_file" <"$fn"
    done
}

time_it() {
    temp_file="tmp_out$1.txt"
    name="func$1"
    { time "$name"; } |& awk -vfn="$name" 'NR==2 {print fn, substr( $2, 3, length( $2) - 3 ) }'
}

for i in {1..6} ; do
    time_it $i
done
```

The output for a single run on my Ubuntu laptop was:

```
func1 1.558
func2 2.273
func3 1.704
func4 1.427
func5 2.188
func6 1.576
```

Note that `func1` is only used for comparison. It does not use piped input.. We see that for this particular run, `func4` and `func6` were approximately as fast as `func1`..